# Using a variable to reference to a form in Access

Tags: vba, variables, ms-access, reference

I'm trying to make code that can be used by multiple different forms.
My problem is that I can't get the form reference right.

Here is my code:

```
Dim FormNaam As String

FormNaam = Screen.ActiveForm.Name

'Realisatie_Euro 6_Transferstraat1
If Forms!Productie_Blok1!txtReal_1_1.Enabled = True Then
    rst.AddNew
    rst!Productielijn = Productielijn
    rst!Lijngedeelte = DLookup("LijngedeelteNr", "TblLijngedeelte", "
[productielijn] = productielijn and [omschrijving] = '" & Forms!
(FormNaam)!lbl_1.Caption & "'")
```

The code that is giving the error is:

```
DLookup("LijngedeelteNr", "TblLijngedeelte", "[productielijn] = 
productielijn and [omschrijving] = '" & Forms!(FormNaam)!lbl_1.Caption & "'")
```

When running this I get a compile error saying the type-declaration character does not match declared data type. I have tried all sort of combinations but cant't get it to work.

So my question is: How can I reference to a specific field on a form, using a variable as the form name?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's either

```
Forms!constantFormName!Property
```

or

```
Forms(strVarFormName)!Property
```

So:

```
Forms(FormNaam)!lbl_1.Caption
```

or a little more straightforward:

```
Dim myForm As Access.Form
Set myForm = Screen.ActiveForm

"...[omschrijving] = '" & myForm!lbl_1.Caption & "'"
```

Comment: Thanks Andre, The Forms(FormNaam) solution worked for me.